# Replace js code with aggregate in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have mongo document called groups. This is array of students and subjects.
Each subject has an array of lessons.
Each lesson has an array of marks.

Generally, document looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "students": [
      { "_id": "0", "firstName": "Bob", "lastName": "Jhonson" },
      { "_id": "1", "firstName": "Jackie", "lastName": "Chan" }
      // other students ...
    ],
    "subjects": [
      {
        "name": "Algebra",
        "lessons": [
          {
            "date": 1489363200,
            "marks": [
              { "student_id": "0", "value": 5 },
              { "student_id": "1", "value": 4 }
              // other marks...
            ]
          }, {
            "date": 1489622400,
            "marks": [
              { "student_id": "0", "value": 3 },
              { "student_id": "1", "value": 2 }
              // other marks...
            ]
          }
          // other lessons...
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then I use js function to transform this data to something like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5a89ca11abc4ffd25a430420",
    "subjects": [
      {
        "name": "Algebra",
        "dates": [1489363200, 1489622400],
        "students": [
          {
            "_id": "0",
            "firstName": "Bob",
            "lastName": "Jhonson",
            "marks": [ 5, 3 ]
          },
          {
            "_id": "1",
            "firstName": "Jackie",
            "lastName": "Chan",
            "marks": [ 4, 2 ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Function which transforms json document:

```
function transformData (groups) { // groups - array
  let newGroups = [];

  for (let group of groups) {
    newGroup = {};

    for (let key in group) {
      if (key === 'students' || key === 'subjects') continue;
      newGroup[key] = group[key];
    }
    newGroup.subjects = [];

    for (let subject of group.subjects) {
      let newSubject = {
        name: subject.name,
        dates: [],
        students: []
      };

      for (let student of group.students) {
        let index = newSubject.students.push(student) - 1;
        newSubject.students[index].marks = [];
      }

      for (let lesson of subject.lessons) {
        let index = newSubject.dates.push(lesson.date) - 1;

        for (let mark of lesson.marks) {
          for (let student of newSubject.students) {
            if (student._id !== mark.student_id) continue;

            while(student.marks.length !== index) {
              student.marks.push(null);
            }
            student.marks.push(mark.value);
          }
        }
      }

      newGroup.subjects.push(newSubject);
    }

    newGroups.push(newGroup);
  }

  return newGroups;
}
```

How can I replace this function with mongodb aggregation?

Comment: Is `groups` the collection name or a document with a field called `groups` which is an array with only one element?

Comment: groups is a collection name